# Use with sharing for @AuraEnabled Apex controllers with Implicit Sharing

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I have been tasked to handle a test for release updates which is (Make Flows Respect Access Modifiers for Legacy Apex Actions). I am new to development and this is my first release updates testing, no idea where to start or what to do.

How can assess the impact of this release update?

Ensure that all your @AuraEnabled Apex code explicitly controls sharing behavior using the with sharing or without sharing keywords. If all your @AuraEnabled code explicitly sets sharing behavior, this update has no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first let's explain how record security (or sharing) works. This is basically a set of mechanisms that makes a record hidden / visible / editable by a specific user. There are many features that affect record security, os owd, sharing rules, manual sharing... and more. One of these features is the "view all", "modify all", "modify all data" and "view all data" checkboxes that you can check in a user profile. For instance the sys admin profile, views all records, because it has those checkboxes checked.

Apex classes "with sharing" respect record security. Eg: if the running user (A) has access to record "ACME", and there's a query in the class that retrieves accounts, the "ACME" record will be retrieved. But, if the running user (B) doesn't have access to it, it won't.

Before "inherited sharing" existed, many devs tended to leave the classes with no sharing clause, which was a kind of inherited sharing, but with [some differences](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264509/inherited-sharing-vs-no-sharing-declaration#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=When%20inherited%20sharing%20is%20used,run%20in%20without%20sharing%20mode.). As of today, we recommend to use "inherited sharing" instead of not indicating a sharing clause.

A way to test if a method is enforcing "with sharing" (via its class) is the next one. Let's imagine the method does an SOQL query that retrieves Tasks. I pick Task because it has a private sharing model (owd), which means users can't see tasks other users have created, by default (although the sys admin can, because of the "view all", etc. checkboxes !).

What we'd do in the test is to create a Task (will run as system user), and then run the method as another user (eg: a user with the "Standard Profile"). As the "Standard Profile" user doesn't have "View all"/"Modify all" checkboxes checked, it shouldn't be able to view records created by other users.

In Apex, you can run tests as if you were user A or B, in what regards to sharing (bear in mind other layers of security as CRUD or FLS won't be enforces using this method). This is [Test.runAs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm).

Here you have the sample code:

Class to be tested:

```
public with sharing class TaskSelector {
  public static List<Task> getTasks() {
    return [SELECT Subject FROM Task];
  }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
private with sharing class TaskSelectorTest {
  @isTest
  static void taskSelectorEnforcesSharing() {
    // This code runs as the system user
    Task systemUserTask = new Task(Subject = 'Call Alba');
    insert systemUserTask;

    String uniqueUserName =
      'standarduser' +
      DateTime.now().getTime() +
      '@testorg.com';

    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

    User u = new User(
      Alias = 'standt',
      Email = 'standarduser@testorg.com',
      EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
      LastName = 'Testing',
      LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
      LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
      ProfileId = p.Id,
      TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
      UserName = uniqueUserName
    );

    System.runAs(u) {
      // The following code runs as user 'u'
      System.assertEquals(
        0,
        taskSelector.getTasks().size(),
        'Expected 0 tasks returned'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is how to do it in Apex, but obviously, you can do the same test manually, creating records logged in with different users and seeing how your flow + apex code retrieve them.

Said that, probably your class to be tested doesn't use Tasks as mine. You'll need to understand how sharing works, what's how the objects used in your class should behave in regards to sharing, and find a valid way to test your class logic. But I hope that at least this helped understanding what you need to do.

Comment: Super clear and insightful, Thank you so much @Alba!